# Having Difficulty with grid Layout, Row Takes up way more than content height

Tags: html, css

I got this said responsive grid,
where i want the nav to take up the first row,
I manged to accomplish that, however the height of the nav becomes half the page,

I've manged to figured out the the grid splits into 2 rows, based on the height the list was initially,
the row doesnt seem to take the new height of the list.
The nav has alot of empty space below it.

What i actually want the following items to appear just below it , no extra space

and BTW, without knowing the placment , how would one go about

The Html:

```
 <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <header>
                <h3>BestBook INC</h3>
            </header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="hide">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-cog fa-lg"></i>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">register <i class="fas fa-user-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Log Out <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg "></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cart">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

nav{
    grid-column: 1/-1
}
nav ul{
    display: grid;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
nav a{
    background-color: var(--primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:var(--dark);
    padding: 0.48rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    box-shadow: var(--shadow);
}
```

Comment: Can you add you requirement as a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height: 100vh; from container css.

Check out this pen I created.

https://codepen.io/aakash-sharma1/pen/yLNQWMv`height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 0):

You probably really want to use `flex`

```css
header>*{
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  width:100vw; height:100vh; text-align:center;
}
nav>ul{
  display:flex; list-style:none; padding:0;
}
nav>ul>li>a{
  text-decoration:none; padding: 0.48rem; font-size:1.1rem; white-space:nowrap;
}
nav>ul>li{
  flex:1;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<header><h3>BestBook INC</h3></header>
<div class='container'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Login <i class='fas fa-user fa-lg'></i></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>register <i class='fas fa-user-plus fa-lg'></i></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Log Out <i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg '></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```